# Where did this class come from?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

How would you go about establishing where a class ( or maybe resource ) has been loaded from?

I am trying to work out exactly where a class has been loaded from. Does anyone know if you can find out the following:

1. Which Jar file did the class come from ?
2. What classloader loaded the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class `Class` has an instance method `getClassLoader()` that returns a reference to the class loader that loaded the class it represents. Note that this can return `null`. See [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader%28%29).

So, if you wanted to know which classloader loaded `String` (just as an example) you could do:

```
ClassLoader loader = String.class.getClassLoader();
```

or:

```
ClassLoader loader = "I'm a String".getClass().getClassLoader();
```

Comment: Which would probably be `null`. Also class loaders often load classes and resources from multiple locations.

Answer (score 3):

For a class one solution is `MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`. (Actually, may have a `null` `ProtectionDomain` or that may not hava a `CodeSource`. My also throw a `SecurityException`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get an URL by calling MyClass.class.getResource("MyClass.class") for instance.

Answer (score 1):

i think you will get the answer here :

http://www.jugpadova.it/articles/2005/11/13/from-which-jar-a-class-was-loaded

http://www.techtalkz.com/java/102114-how-find-jar-file-ava-class-all-successorshad-been-loaded.html

Answer (score 0):

I would go about that with the `-verbose:class` command line option, saving the output to a text file and then use grep (or the DOS find if you are windows) to see details on how that class is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an instance of the class
insta.getClass().getClassLoader().getName() -->this is the classloader that loaded the class

insta.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()- where the class was loader from